# Message sent to deallocated instance in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsurlconnection, release, exc-bad-access

I am new to iPhone,

I am creating NSURLConnection as suggested by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
but my app crashes when i Dismiss my view, i have tried concept of `NSZombieEnabled` which shows me `-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x68b8f40`

I am displaying a webpage in `Webview`, When users clicks on download link in the webview then `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method will be called inside this method i am creating `NSURLConnection`.

here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1
{
    [receivedData appendData:data1];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    DirPath=[self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

     NSLog(@"DirPath=%@",DirPath);
    [receivedData writeToFile:DirPath atomically:YES];

    UIAlertView* Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Complete !"
                                                         message:nil delegate:nil 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [Alert show];
    [Alert release];


    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error1
{
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error1 localizedDescription],
          [[error1 userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {


    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.

            Durl=[[url absoluteString]copy];

            //Checking for Duplicate .FILE at downloaded path....

            BOOL success =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
            lastPath=[[url lastPathComponent] copy];

            if (success) //if duplicate file found...
            {
                UIAlertView* Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This FILE is already present in Library."
                                                                     message:@"Do you want to Downlaod again ?" delegate:self 
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No",nil];
                [Alert show];
                [Alert release];

            }
            else  //if duplicate file not found directly start download...
            {
                // Create the request.
                NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Durl]
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

                // create the connection with the request and start loading the data
                NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
                if (theConnection) {
                    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
                    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Inform the user that the connection failed."); 
                }

    return YES;   
}
```

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Comment this line and check [connection release];

Comment: Already tried this but not working.

Comment: did you comment receivedData as well?

Comment: ya i tried with both possibility, With comment and without comment but still crashes.

Comment: NSLog(@" connection %p",connection); NSLog(@" receivedData %p",receivedData); NSLog(@" webView %p",webView); Print object address and check which one is causing the crash. And also call retain on both connection and receivedData objects.

Comment: I wrote all 3 logs in `connectionDidFinishLoading` all 3 shows me some hexadecimal values, is it wrong ? how to call retain ?

Comment: [receivedData retain]; [connection retain];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your implementation of dealloc you are resetting the `delegate` to `nil`. Another place for doing so would be `viewWillDisappear:`.

The reason for your app to crash / access a zombie is that the `UIWebView` instance will possibly be trying to call back the viewController even though it has already been deallocated. To prevent that, you have to set the `delegate` of that `UIWebView` back to `nil` before the viewController goes out of scope. That is a general issue when working with delegation prior to iOS5's ARC implementation. iOS5 finally offers weak references, those actually `nil` themselves once their instance is getting deallocated.

Example A:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [...]
    _webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Example B:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappaer:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappaer:animated];
    _webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

---

Edit:
After reading your question once again, I realised that the zombie is a UIView or a UIControl since the message is sent to a CALayer. Make sure your problem actually is related to the web view by temporarily removing all webView related code.

Comment: I am not sure but problem is not related to webview, it is related to `NSURLConnection` connection caushes crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with this  `NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`

You are creating an instance of `NSURLConnection` with delegate self, when you dismiss the view everything get `deallocated` on that view. But when the `NSURLConnection` tries to call it's delegate method crash will occur.

So you need to set the delegate of `NSURLConnection` to nil in your `viewWillDisappear` for doing this, you need to create object of `NSURLConnection` in interface.

```
@interface yourClass
{
   NSURLConnection *theConnection;
}
@end
```

in .m

```
theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

- (void)viewWillDisappaer:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappaer:animated];
    theConnection.delegate = nil;
}
```